# Handling multipart post method request in Nodejs throwing Unexpected Field Error

Tags: android, node.js

I am trying a request a `post` method from Android App using `Loopj Async Http Client`, and handling the request using Node Server which uses `Multer`
By using the code Below

**Step-1**

```
public static void post(String url, File entity, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        try {
            params.put("image",entity);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }
```

The getAbsoluteUrl return the actual Url to post the request

**Step-2 (Node Server)**

```
router.post('/upload_image', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
});
```

But, after receiving the request my node js server is throwing some error like this which i cannot Understand, After few hours of googling and searching for other option i am still clueless to solve the issue.

Here is the issue:

```
POST /upload_image 500 1537.367 ms - 2057
Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/lib/make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/index.js:39:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:112:7)
    at Busboy.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at Busboy.emit (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:31:35)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
    at HeaderParser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at HeaderParser._finish (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:68:8)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:40:12)
    at SBMH.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at SBMH._sbmh_feed (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:95:16)
    at SBMH.push (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:56:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:46:19)
    at Dicer._oninfo (/home/jkrishna/Documents/ProjectX/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:197:25)
```

Comment: You forgot to show how you are setting up the `multer` middleware.

Comment: @mscdex , I have added multer in this way app.use(multer({dest: images_path}).single('file'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've configured `multer` to look for a file whose field name is `'file'`, but in your Android code you're sending a field named `'image'`. Change one or the other and it should work.